# Kotlin use UInt for array access and constant

Tags: kotlin, unsigned

unsigned data types could be nice for array access. Usually the indexes are unsigned anyway. But currently I cannot directly do this. E.g. this code.

```
val foo = 1.toUInt()

"foo"[foo]
```

fails to compile with:

```
error: type mismatch: inferred type is UInt but Int was expected
```

what is the best way to deal with this? Sure I could do:

```
val foo = 1.toUInt()

"foo"[foo.toInt()]
```

but this feels wrong somehow. UInt is an inline class anyway and gets erased to Int anyway - so I think this should not be needed. Anyone saw a kotlin/KEEP for this?
Also wondering about how to define unsigned constants. Unfortunately the constructor is private so I cannot do e.g.

```
const val foo = UInt(42)
```

and

```
const val foo = 42.toUInt()
```

fails with `42.toUInt()` is not a constant value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless/until there's built-in support for this, you can easily add it yourself.  For example, for standard arrays:

```
operator fun <T> Array<T>.get(index: UInt) = this[index.toInt()]
```

And for `CharSequence`s (which aren't arrays):

```
operator fun CharSequence.get(index: UInt) = this[index.toInt()]
```

With that in scope, your `"foo"[foo]` works fine!

(You'd also need separate overloads for `IntArray` &c if you used those.)

Comment: Thanks! Hope this makes it to the standard library at some point

Answer (score 3):

In the array indexing question, `.toInt()` is the best method I have found.

Declaring a const, you can append a "u" to any integer constant, or "uL" for a long constant, like `42u` or `1_000_000_000_000uL`.